# Auto horizontal scroll with a chartengine - Android

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, autoscroll

I am trying to get a graph in my app to scroll horizontally automatically when the values hit the right corner, so that you do not have to manually scroll when values go out of range.

I have it like this so far:

```
   mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
   mRenderer.setXAxisMax(199);
   mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-2);
   mRenderer.setYAxisMax(3);
   mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
   mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
   mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
```

[image]

You can see the red, black and blue lines as they run off the right side of the screen,
however I have to manually scroll to the right to see the rest.

*edit*: Also the data coming in is dynamic, so I can't get the max values to set what appears in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the X axis, you need to modify the visible axis range this way:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
```

Don't forget to call `repaint` once you do the above:

```
mChartView.repaint();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. What do you mean by the `mixX` and `maxX`. I need it to scroll to the newest value. When I tried this method it just zooms the graph to show these values. Do you mean to set maxX as an int, e.g. to 100, then increment it by one every howevermany ms?

Comment: So I guess you will need minX to stay at 0, so no need to change it. The maxX value will be something very close to the latest added value or even the value itself.

Comment: But i am doing the same for my case its not working for example i have setXmax(50) when i am changing the values setMax(100) it should display 100 in x axis but its not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

First find the maximum value for x axis say maxX and maximum value for y axis say maxY

then

```
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxY);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
```